# redactor attach keyUp callback after initiation

Tags: redactor

am trying to attach keyUp callback for redactor after initiation, the textarea is initiated with the following

```
$("#id_article-content").redactor({
"lang": "en", 
"toolbarFixed": true, 
"direction": "ltr", 
"minHeight": 400, 
"buttons": ["formatting", "|", "bold", "italic", "|", "orderedlist", "|", "link", "|", "horizontalrule"]
});
```

Problem is I cannot attach to the above my callback and I must do it after its has been ran, am trying to use the below code

```
$('#id_article-content').keyupCallback = function (e) {
    console.log('ddd');
};
```

but that not working, would appreciate any help or pointers I can get on this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    keyupCallback: function(e)
    {
        console.log(this.get());
    }
});
```

[Documentation](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/#h-keyupCallback)

Answer (score 0):

just a quick guess, after looking at the API I think the code should look like this (untested):

```
$('#id_article-content').redactor({
keyupCallback: function (e) {
    console.log('ddd');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add callbacks on the initial setup of your redactor.  If you try to do it afterward, in a separate call, it doesn't work.

```
    $('#redactor).redactor({
        buttons: ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'deleted', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'horizontalrule'],
        plugins: ['fontcolor'],
        pastePlainText: true,
        wym: true,
        iframe: false,
        focus: true,
        keyupCallback: function (e) {
           console.log(this.get());
    }
  });
```